# Magento catalog price rules discount doesn't work with products with custom options

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, shopping-cart

We have added several catalog price rules in our magento stores, but it seems that they don't get applied with additional costs that we set inside products with custom options, but they only work with standard product price, is there a way to fix this? thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you're just missing one thing.

On your catalog price rule, go under *Actions* and change the item called *Enable Discount to Subproducts* to Yes.

And then set this number to be the same as your original discount above.

Example: If you're selling a pair of shoes, and red ones normally cost $10 more.

With the subproduct rule set to no, the $10 mark-up stays at $10, even if your shoes are 50% off. If you turn that subproduct option on, you set a separate line item, to change the mark-up value - so it's shoes 50% off and then 50% off the markup for red ones.

Comment: unfortunately it's not working, because I don't think they are subproducts: they're just normal products with an additional price added to some custom options

Answer (score 1):

Catalog price rules don't work on simple product's options, they only work on sub-products i.e. childs of configurable products.
If you want to have discounts on single product options you have to create as many products as the options to discount and then to associate them to a configurable product.